# VCE Init error (-110)

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, radeon, thinkpad

When I am booting ubuntu 16.04.1 from my ssd card, I am getting the grub menu. Choosing "Ubuntu" will result in screen where theese lines are repeatedly output.

```
[   586.8503085] radeon 000:05:00:0: VCE Init error (-110).
```

I am having a Lenovo ThinkPad with a AMD Radeon R7 M265 Series graphics card.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> lets me see the Ubuntu start screen for a second and the computer will be rebooted.

Now, this seems to be an error half a year old. Is there anything I can do? Should I try an older Ubuntu version? Which one?

I know there are a lot of postings on this subject, still I have not seen an answer that convincingly solves the problem for anyone.